# Python, Django with PyCharm. Message error: "No module named M2Crypto" How resolve?

Tags: python, pycharm, m2crypto

I received this message: "No module named M2Crypto"
I have already install M2Crypto with the command "pip install M2Crypto" and when I re-run it, I got the message: "Requirement already satisfied"

What's the problem with M2Crypto?

Thanks

ps:
I use Linux: 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:12:00 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux, Pycharm and Python2.7 (/usr/bin/python2.7)

Maybe some interpreter option in PyCharm configuration for running the project?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, verify that the **version of pip** is in line with your interpreter.
So for python2.7,

```
pip --version
```

should print something like

```
pip 6.0.8 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

depending on how you've installed it. The important part is in the end, where your interpreter ("python 2.7") should be shown.

Once you're sure to have the right pip-version, ensure your **package is correctly installed**. It should usually be installed in the directory printed out previously by pip (e.g. /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/).

Assume you've already done this, **what else** can go wrong to make your interpreter not finding the 'M2Crypto' package?

python uses the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable for module lookups. So, there's the possibility, that your `PYTHONPATH` variable has been changed. Try running your program by adding the above-mentioned path to `PYTHONPATH` and either exporting it before running your webserver:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/:$PYTHONPATH
# run your server here
```

or by prepending the same variable to your command:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/:$PYTHONPATH python <run-stuff-here>
```

This should make your program find the M2Crypto module.